# How to save another person's Dropbox file to my own Dropbox account?

Tags: dropbox, download

I want to download a large file hosted on Dropbox. I tried downloading it with 45kbps download rate and it would take 3 hours. The connection is intermittent, so my download was cut.

Is it possible to treat the file as your own and then put it to your own Dropbox? From there, it would continue downloading.

Comment: "and it is not about …" ... "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: dropbox also refers to an application

Comment: I'd use wget for this, it tends to be a lot more robust than any browser's downloader, and it can continue a file with the -c flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, thats not possible.

why dont you just use a download manager, like IDM for example, and when your connection cuts out, just resume from where you left off ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, you can try the addon DownThemAll. It's a great download manager.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox added this feature a while back. When you click **Download** on a file, there should be an option for **Save to my Dropbox**

[image: 'Save to my Dropbox' option]

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to transfer, you are more than welcome to use Cloudsfer to transfer the file from one Dropbox account into another.
Our service is cloud based and will allow you to migrate the data without using any bandwidth or experiencing any download errors.

If you find this helpful, please visit our website for more information.

Kindest Regards, 
Roy - The Cloudsfer Team
http://www.cloudsfer.com/

Comment: So you are promoting your software here on this 7 year old or so post, correct? This is a link only answer too by the way.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't unless the owner of the file decides to share the directory with you. Of course you can try to use a download manager to resume the download.